# Want to manipulate array in response of curl request

Tags: php, curl

In my application i am making **curl request** and in response getting an array, but somehow not able to **manipulate** that array also **is_array()** not recognize that as an array.

code for curl request is :

```
$curls="http://localhost/myapp/alertentryxml.php?".$compurl; 

           $ch = curl_init();
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$curls);
           curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
           $store = curl_exec($ch);
```

and generating an multidimensional array from **alertentryxml.php** with

```
print_r($data);
```

**$data** is multidimensional array.

when i checked response in above **$store** variable, it shows an array in response but not working as a array.
**What i have done wrong here?
is it possible to send array as a response or not?**

Answer (score 1):

You can't just do a `print_r($data)` and expect PHP to be able to interperate this as an array, it's just text. Lookup what [print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) does:

> Prints human-readable information about a variable

What you should do is:

alertentryxml.php

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

and then in your curl request:

```
$store = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
```

I've chosen JSON in this instance as it's my personal preference, but you could also send the data as XML or any other format as long as you decode it the same way it was encoded at the other end.